# How do I determine the [fig]size of a matplotlib.image.AxesImage in pixel?

Tags: matplotlib

This code renders the Lenna image with matplotlib,

```
import urllib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imgurl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png/330px-Lenna_%28test_image%29.png'
f = urllib.request.urlopen(imgurl)
img = plt.imread(f)
axi = plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

where `axi` is an instance of [matplotlib.image.AxesImage](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/image_api.html)

How do I determine the [fig]size of the AxesImage in pixel? the expected value might (330, 330)

I tried `axi.get_window_extent()` and got

Bbox([[112.68, 36.00000000000003], [330.12, 253.44000000000003]])

Where do those values (112.68, 330.12) come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To get the raw image size

Use `AxesImage.get_size()`:

```py
axi.get_size()

# (330, 330)
```

---

#### To convert the axes extent into pixels

Adjust the window extent by `Figure.dpi`:

```py
axi = plt.imshow(img)
fig = plt.gcf()

bbox = axi.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
width = bbox.width * fig.dpi
height = bbox.height * fig.dpi

# 334.79999999999995 217.43999999999997
```

The reason this is *not* 330x330 is because of how `plt.imshow()` handles the aspect ratio. If you plot with `aspect='auto'`, the underlying axes' shape becomes visible:

```py
axi = plt.imshow(img, aspect='auto')
```

[image: lenna with auto aspect]

---

#### To coerce the underlying axes into desired shape

Manually define `figsize` and `rect` using the pixel dimensions and desired dpi:

```py
width_px, height_px, _ = img.shape
dpi = 96

figsize = (width_px / dpi, height_px / dpi) # inches
rect = [0, 0, 1, 1] # [left, bottom, width, height] as fraction of figsize

fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi) # in inches
axes = fig.add_axes(rect=rect)
axi = axes.imshow(img, aspect='auto')
```

[image: lenna with auto aspect but manual axes]

Then the extent pixels will be exactly 330x330:

```
bbox = axi.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
width = bbox.width * fig.dpi
height = bbox.height * fig.dpi

# 330.0 330.0
```

Answer (score 1):

axi.get_size() gives (330,330) - why not use that?